# Separating a list of entries by the first letter in a given field

Tags: php

I'm trying to list a series of entries by the first letter of the entry title.

How would I do this, and b, separate each letter per each of the Alphabet.

Thanks

Let's say I have two titles:

```
Much Ado About Nothing
The Tempest
```

I'd need to separate the titles according to the first letter:

```
//
K
L
M - Much Ado About Nothing
N
//
S
T The Tempest
U
V
```

etc.

EDIT: This is the array I have, and I need to select the title from it:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Test Article
        [author] => Shamil
        [date] => 1309039548
        [summary] => Summary of test article
        [content] => 

Technical article Content.


        [category] => technical
        [published] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the input is and what the output should look like please?

Comment: do you get your titles form a Database, file or any other resources?

Comment: Do you want to store this somewhere? Or just create an array and use it in the application? Is the "list of entries" an array?

Comment: I don't need to store this- but it just needs to be dynamically generated. The titles are stored in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all these entries comes in an array, and the titles are capitalized, you can do the following:

```
$entries = array(...); // the original entries
sort($entries);

$alphabetized = array();
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    $alphabetized[$letter] = array();
}

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    array_unshift($alphabetized[$entry[0]], $entry);
}
```

The only problem with this algorithm is that it will alphabetize something like "The Matrix" under T instead of M.  But at least this is a start.

**Update:**
Here's code I made to handle "The" and "A":

```
<?php
$entries = array(
    array('title' => 'Much Ado About Nothing'),
    array('title' => 'Star Wars'),
    array('title' => 'The Tempest'),
    array('title' => 'A Wrinkle In Time'),
    array('title' => 'Star Trek'),
    array('title' => 'The'),
    array('title' => 'A')
);

function shamil_title_compare($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}

usort($entries, 'shamil_title_compare');

$alphabetized = array();
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    $alphabetized[$letter] = array();
}

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $title = $entry['title'];
    $firstWord = strtok($title, ' ');
    if (!in_array($firstWord, array('The', 'A'))) {
        $alphabetized[$firstWord[0]][] = $entry;
    } else {
        $nextWord = strtok(' ');
        if ($nextWord !== false) {
            $alphabetized[$nextWord[0]][] = $entry;
        } else {
            $alphabetized[$firstWord[0]][] = $entry;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
I've updated my code to output the alphabetized list into an html unordered list:

```
<?php
$entries = array(
    array('title' => 'Much Ado About Nothing'),
    array('title' => 'Star Wars'),
    array('title' => 'A Quantum of Solace'),
    array('title' => 'The Tempest'),
    array('title' => 'Cat Attack'),
    array('title' => 'A Wrinkle In Time'),
    array('title' => 'Star Trek'),
    array('title' => 'The Cat'),
    array('title' => 'Wicked Witch of the West'),
);

// Build a copy of the original, but strip "The" and "A", and lowercase it.
$sort = array();
foreach ($entries as $index => $array)
{
    $title = strtoupper($array['title']);
    list($head, $tail) = explode(' ', $title, 2);

    if (($head !== 'A') and ($head !== 'THE'))
    {
        $sort[] = $title;
    }
    else if ($tail != '')
    {
        $sort[] = $tail;
    }
    else
    {
        $sort[] = $head;
    }
}

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $entries);

$alphabetized = array();
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter)
{
    $alphabetized[$letter] = array();
}

foreach ($sort as $index => $title)
{
    $letter = $title[0];
    $alphabetized[$letter][] = $entries[$index];
}

// Output as html
foreach ($alphabetized as $letter => $entries)
{
    echo "<h3>{$letter}</h3>", PHP_EOL,
        "<ul>", PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($entries as $entry)
    {
        echo "<li>{$entry['title']}</li>", PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "</ul>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I guess one improvement to this algorithm you could make is to check the first word of the title to see if it's something like "The" or "A", and if it is, use `substr` to get the next word and alphabetize according to that instead.

Comment: It's not liking `    array_unshift($alphabetized[$entry[$firstWord[0]]], $entry);`     Notice: Undefined index: T.

Comment: @Shamil I've updated to simpler code, it doesn't give any errors or notices when I tested it.  Try it out and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Integrating this is my thing in painful -.-.

Comment: Right, I've edited the question to include the array that I currently have.

Comment: All it echoes out is: Array. Nope :/

Comment: Did you try `print_r()` instead of `echo`?  I'm not sure if you can echo an array, I'll have to double check...

Comment: Sorry, no you can't. Right, even though I've got an array - how do I use it to display the titles?

Comment: @Shmail ok I checked, you can't echo an array and see its contents like that, you have to use either `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Comment: @Shamil do you want to just list the titles line by line?

Comment: Hi, I've just sorted them out. Now, one more thing. Sorting them, as seen on a wiki page: http://wiki.solusvm.com/index.php/Category:Documentation

Comment: @Shamil I'm not sure what you mean, didn't the solution I gave you already alphabetize the entries for you?

Comment: It did, however, I need to separate them further, into categories per alphabet letter.

Comment: @Shamil the solution I gave you already does that too...did you mean that you wanted to know how to convert the array into html markup?  If it's html, I might be able to help you with that, but if it's wiki markup that you want, you're really better off just asking another question on stack overflow for that.

Comment: How do I print out the letter of the alphabet before it echoes the $entry['title']?

Comment: @Shamil if you're willing to wait a few hours, I can try to help you with that, otherwise, you should just ask another question on stack overflow and see if other people can help you with that.  You need to be specific on what kind of output you want (html, wiki markup, etc) so people can help you better.

Comment: I'm here for the next few hours. It would be HTML output. If you prefer, I can open a new question now, so that mods don't step into this one?

Comment: @Shamil I'm not concerned about the moderators, but I do think it's more to your benefit if you just ask another question, so that more people can help you, I think you'll arrive at a solution to your problem faster that way.

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499790/sorting-titles-and-displaying-alphabetically-with-alphabet-letter-preceding-entr

Comment: @Shamil I've added new code that will output an html list for you.  I've also improved the alphabetization, I think my previous code may not alphabetize correctly.